# Dalhousie to Udawalawe?

Tags: transportation, sri-lanka

How can I travel from Dalhousie to Udawalawe? Are there any sensible public transport options or would a driver be required?  I intend to do this after descending Adams Peak.

Comment: Are Dalhousie and Udawalawe in Sri Lanka?

Comment: Dalhousie appears to be in India, from a cursory google search, unless there's more than one?

Comment: Ah yes, after a slightly more detailed search, there's also one in Sri Lanka...

Answer (score 2):

We took a similar trip from Tissamaharama to Dalhousie with a private driver (we more or less drove past Udawalawe, so the answer might be applicable for you too).

Our host in Tissamaharama organized a private taxi for the trip. We were a group of three on that trip and paid around 5000 sri lankan rupees per person.

My advice: Ask your host if he knows a trustworthy driver.

Answer (score 1):

One option is by public taxi.

Rome2Rio doesn't cover everything (so there may well be other options), but according to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Udawalawe/Dalhousie-Sri-Lanka) a public taxi is the only option that they're aware of, would take about 3.25 hours, and cost you in the realm of $55, assuming you aren't ripped off.